# Effectively print a long sequence

Tags: java, algorithm

I've to print a number which is a huge sequence of 5's and 3's (upto 100,000 ints). Instead of storing it in array, I just kept their count in `noOfThrees` and `noOfFives`.

For simplicity call this number `x`.                                .

Since I have to print the largest number in the sequence, `x` will be initially 5's and then followed with 3's (I have working logic to print if there's no 5's or no 3's)

To print the number, I am using a for loop like this :

```
for(int i=0; i<noOfFives; i++) 
    System.out.print(5);
for(int i=0; i<noOfThrees; i++)
    System.out.print(3);
```

But if `x` is a 100,000 long int number, it takes about 4-5sec to print it on console which is not desirable.

My take:

- If the `noOfFives` is even, then print `55` in the for loop which increases the performance by x2 and increment the loop by two, else
- Use the same for loop as above. Same goes for `noOfThrees`.

But the problem here is if it's odd, it will again end up printing in steps of 1. How do I effectively print this sequence?

Comment: What practical use does this have? Why do you need it to be faster?

Comment: @AndyTurner I'am solving a challenge on online judge which causes timeout if execution time is >4sec

Comment: what about a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) instead of a simple `int`?

Comment: If it is being judged online, it's not really printing to a console. Since you aren't flushing, your output will be buffered; as such, writing in larger chunks won't make much difference.

Comment: @AndyTurner when I print it on my machine, it takes around 4-5sec, I believe that's what is causing timeout, since it pases all test cases, and causes timeout on others.

Comment: How long does it take to run if you pipe the output to /dev/null?

Comment: You can try [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29) to pad with 5 and 3, instead of looping though them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to output a string to system out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823095/whats-the-fastest-way-to-output-a-string-to-system-out)

Comment: Did you try to make sure `System.out` is buffered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think that the number of `print` calls is the issue, you could reduce it to just 1: put the right number of 3s and 5s into a char array, then print that:

```
char[] cs = new char[noOfFives + noOfThrees];
Arrays.fill(cs, 0, noOfFives, '5');
Arrays.fill(cs, noOfFives, cs.length, '3');
System.out.print(cs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a bit strange - I wonder whether the logical way to make your code faster is to look elsewhere at how these values are calculated.

However I think it would significantly increase your performance to first build the string in memory and then print it.

I also think you should look at [Why is printing "B" dramatically slower than printing "#"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947452/why-is-printing-b-dramatically-slower-than-printing?rq=1) which might shed some interesting light on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use loop unrolling, it can reduce execute time of loop.
for example:

```
    for(int i=0; i<noOfFives; i+=5) {
        System.out.print(5);
        System.out.print(5);
        System.out.print(5);
        System.out.print(5);
        System.out.print(5);
    }
```

For more details look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling

Comment: In all likelyhood the number of `System.out.print` is the problem, not the number of loops.