# Convert int to byte array and print to console with System.out.write method

Tags: java, arrays, int, nio, outputstream

I have this program:

```
public class Duplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = "hz".getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            System.out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
    }
}
```

After start I have output:

> hzhzhzhzhzhzhzhz.....hz

But if I try convert `int`  to byte array and print:

```
public class Duplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(666).array();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            System.out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
    }
}
```

After start I have output:

> �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �
>   �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �

I want to print `666` 10,000,000 times on each line of console and not use more than 20MB memory or 1 second.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** If I will use example @Justin - `Integer.toString(i).getBytes()` I have this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is not the call to `Integer.valueOf(666).toString()` since it is executed only once. The actual problem is, that the call to `System.out.write()` has some overhead. This can be avoided by using a larger buffer which is filled with some repetitions of the input value.

Here is what I came up with:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
byte[] bytes = String.valueOf(666).getBytes();

// use 20 mb of memory for the output buffer
int size = 20 * 1000 * 1000  / bytes.length;


byte[] outBuffer = new byte[size * bytes.length];
// fill the buffer which is used for System.out.write()
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, outBuffer, i * bytes.length, bytes.length);
}

// perform the actual writing with the larger buffer
int times = 10_000_000 / size;
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.write(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length);
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "Millis");
```

Which takes about 600ms to output 666 ten million times.

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct.  If you cast `int` 666 to a `char`, that's what would be displayed.  If you want to literally print out 666, you would need to convert the `int` to a `String` first:

```
byte[] bytes = Integer.toString(input).getBytes();
```

Comment: if that were enough I would have done so. I'm not just so freaked out. I cannot print lines in such a loop because there is another task that requires it.

Comment: @ip696 I can't make sense of your comment. This answer seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I edited the question especially for you

Comment: What monitoring tool are you using?

Comment: I use JProfiler

Comment: I will investigate further, but see if this helps also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823095/whats-the-fastest-way-to-output-a-string-to-system-out